# Homework: Solve the poisson equation in the outer sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Our teacher asked us to solve the poisson equation:
\begin{eqnarray}\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\Delta u &= &0
\\ u|_{\partial \overline{B(0,R)}} & = & g \\
\lim_{|\vec{x}|\to\infty} u(\vec{x}) & = & 0\end{array}\right.\end{eqnarray}
I tried using the similar technique when the area is bounded. That is , choose an $\epsilon$ sphere near the point $M_0$ I needed and shrink it to zero. But integrating via another boundary: a big sphere is somehow hard since the rate of converging to zero is unknown. Also, the sphere $\overline{B(0,R)}$ is an obstacle fot the integration. Hope to find some hint, thanks!

Comment: This is usually called the Laplace equation ($\Delta u=0$). Why is $u=g$ on the complement of unit ball? Did you mean $u=g$ on the *boundary*? If you know how to solve this PDE on the inside on the unit ball, the [Kelvin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_transform) gives the solution on the outside. The condition at infinity can be enforced by adding a multiple of $(1-R|x|^{-1})$.

Comment: @user111742 Oh,yes. The boundary condition is $g$, sorry for my mistake. By the way, we didn't mention this transformation on the class, it seems that I should prove this result before using it. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Is $g$ a constant ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
We can choose the $\ds{z}$-axis in any direction and use spherical coordinates
$\ds{\pars{r > 0,\ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi,\ 0 \leq \phi < 2\pi}}$. It turns out that the solution is $\ds{\phi}$-independent and it can be expressed as a linear combination of Legendre Polynomia
$\ds{\braces{{\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}\ \mid\
     \ell = 0,1,2,3,\ldots}}$.
\begin{align}
{\rm u}\pars{r,\theta}&
=\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\pars{A_{\ell}r^{\ell} + {B_{\ell} \over r_{\ell + 1}}}{\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}
\end{align}

> Since $\ds{\lim_{r\ \to\ \infty}{\rm u}\pars{r,\theta} = 0}$, we set $\ds{A_{\ell} = 0\,,\forall\ \ell}$. Then,
>   $$
> {\rm u}\pars{r,\theta}
> =\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{B_{\ell} \over r_{\ell + 1}}
> {\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}
> ={B_{0} \over r} + \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}{B_{\ell} \over r_{\ell + 1}}
> {\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}
> $$
>   The boundary condition at $\ds{r = R}$ is given by:
>   \begin{align}
> g&={\rm u}\pars{R,\theta}
> ={{B_{0} \over R}}
> +\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}{B_{\ell} \over R_{\ell + 1}}
> {\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}
> \end{align}

Since $\ds{g}$ is a constant, we'll have
$\quad\ds{B_{\ell} = 0\,,\forall\ \ell \geq 1\quad\imp\quad B_{0} = gR}$

> $$
> \mbox{Then,}\quad
> \color{#66f}{\large{\rm u}\pars{r,\theta}={R \over r}\,g}
> $$

Since the $\ds{\tt OP}$ never answer my comment, I assumed that $\ds{g}$ is a constant.

Comment: Thank you Felix. The $g$ here is not a constant, but a function depend on the position. Apologize for not responsing your comment, since I've got the answer for the question long ago.